# identity versus equality for None in Python

Tags: python, coding-style

Various Python guides say to use `x is None` instead of `x == None`. Why is that? Equality is used for comparing values, so it seems natural to ask if `x` has the value `None`, denoted with `==` and not `is`. Can someone explain why `is` is the preferred form and show an example where the two do not give the same answer?

Thanks.

Comment: `None` isn't exactly a value. "None is frequently used to represent the absence of a value, as when default arguments are not passed to a function." https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#None

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason people use `is` is because there is no advantage to using `==`.  It is possible to write objects that compare equal to `None`, but it is uncommon.

```
class A(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

print A() == None
```

Output:

```
True
```

The `is` operator is also faster, but I don't consider this fact important.

Comment: I guess you could also add that there is only ever one `None` object, and it has no value. Since all `None`s are the same object, you should use the object identity operator `is`. The comparison operator `==` is inappropriate because `None` has no value.

Comment: @Hamish In what sense does it "have no value"? It *is* a value, just like every other object.

Comment: Why is the `is` operator faster? The reasoning for None being valueless makes no sense to me still... seems arbitrary. How is `None` different from `False` or other values? It's a value equal to `None`... by definition

Comment: @user248237 the `is` operator is potentially faster because it can't be overloaded - there is no equivalent to the chain of calls that `a == b` potentially makes (usually: `a.__eq__(b)`, `b.__eq__(a)` and finally `a is b` - first one to return something other than `NotImplemented` wins). `is` only tests one thing, that Python knows about directly, and always gives you an answer after one test. `None` being valueless is tenuous, but you could think of it like a null C pointer - a pointer's value is what it points to, and a null pointer points to nothing.

Comment: @user248237 but the important thing is that `is None` and `is not None` say exactly what you mean - as DietrichEpp points out, it is *possible* that `x == None` can be overloaded to return True for a non-`None` `x`, possibly via a bug. `is` implies equality (usually, see `float('nan')` for the sole counter-example), but equality doesn't always imply identity even when comparing against singletons (you need the singleton on the LHS, to have its `__eq__` do `return self is other`, and to not compare it against something that subclasses it). `is` says what you mean - much easier than rules.

Comment: @lvc Also, `is` can be implemented directly (in CPython, for example, by comparing pointer values) and doesn't need to make a Python function call at all.

Comment: This answer doesn't directly answer the question (semantic difference between the two operators).

Comment: @JohnClements: I think we might have had a different reading of the question--it sounded to me like the person who asked the question already understood what the semantic difference was.

Answer (score 11):

The `is` keyword tests identity. It is not a comparison operator like `==`. Using `is` does more than test whether two arguments have the same value and/or the same internal structure: namely, it tests whether the two actually refer to the same object in memory. There are numerous implications to this, one of them being that `is` cannot be overloaded, and another being that behavior differs between mutable and immutable types. For example, consider the following:

```
>>> l1 = range(5)
>>> l2 = range(5)
>>> l1 == l2
True
>>> l1 is l2
False
>>> l3 = l1
>>> l1 is l3
True
>>> s1 = "abcde"
>>> s2 = "abcde"
>>> s1 == s2
True
>>> s1 is s2
True
```

Here, because lists are mutable, they cannot share a location in memory, and consequently `is` and `==` yield discrepant results. On the other hand, strings are immutable, and therefore their memory may be pooled in some cases. Basically, `is` can only reliably be used for simple, immutable types, or in instances when multiple names point to exactly the same object in memory (such as the use of `l3` in the above example), and its use indicates a desire to test identity rather than value. I would expect `is` to be slightly faster than `==` because it doesn't perform method lookup, but I could be mistaken. Of course, for complex container objects like lists or dicts, `is` should be much faster than `==` (O(1) vs. O(n), presumably). That said, the speed issue is mostly a moot point, as the two should not be regarded as interchangeable.

Comment: `is` only tests memory location in CPython - in other implementations, it is perfectly free to test other things too (eg, PyPy treats ints specially, letting value determine identity). String interning isn't guaranteed either. You *are* right about `is` not doing method lookups, though - `==` can do two of them (one for each operand) before falling back to an identity check, and either of those can apply any kindof crazy equality rule it wants - including comparing equal to a singleton.

Comment: @lvc, thanks for clarifying. Feel free to edit my post if it needs correcting. I don't claim to be an expert in CPython's internals, or in those of any other implementation.

Comment: I wouldn't call scheme's `eq?` predicate very precise, since a lot of behavior is unspecified.  Its behavior is less specified/precise than `eqv?`, which is in turn less specified/precise than `equal?`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, it's been a long while since I've done any coding in Scheme, but IIRC `equal?` does nothing more than apply `eqv?` to sequence/container types like vectors, cons cells, etc. In particular, `equal?` will return `#t` when comparing distinct objects, stored in different locations in memory, that are structurally identical. Clearly, that doesn't parallel the behavior of `is`. I seem to recall that `eq?` was the most primitive/low-level identity predicate, that much of its behavior in practice defaulted to that of `eqv?`, and that a lot of situations were implementation-dependent.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, q.v., http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Equivalence-Predicates.html, which specifies that `eq?` only returns `#t` when `eqv?` would, and that `eq?` could be done as a simple pointer comparison (whether this is the practice in specific implementations, I have no idea). I was groping for some analogy to Python's `is` in my explanation and for reasons that escape comprehension, `eq?` is what come bubbling up from my subconscious. Of all the Scheme predicates, it seems closest, though whether any Scheme predicate is apposite is another matter.

Comment: I wasn't actually comparing `eq?` to `is`, but pointing out that they are both the least precise tools for comparison, because they have the most leeway to produce different results.  For example, `(eq? 2 2) ==> #f` is fine, `#t` is also fine.  In Python, you can often find `100 + 100 is 200` but `200 + 200 is not 400`.  (The `equal?` predicate has to do a lot more than simply recurse since it has to terminate even for circular input.)

Comment: @DietrichEpp, yes, but I *was* comparing `eq?` to `is` as an analogous identity operator from another language. Nowhere did I suggest that people use `eq?` in place of more appropriate predicates, nor did I claim that the parallel is exact, so I'm not quite sure where your objection lies. In any case, it's obviously not the right tool in a lot of situations, and clearly both `eq?` and `eqv?` exhibit ambiguous or implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, and if your point is that people should use pure comparison operators rather than identity predicates when value/structural equality is the important criterion, I agree unreservedly. Does my original response to the OP's question give a different impression?

Comment: I was responding to the comment that `eq?` is the most "semantically precise", when it is actually the least precisely defined operator.  I wasn't trying to say anything else.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, you're right, that was a poor choice of words. I'm deleting that whole reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

PEP 8 says:
"Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with 'is' or 'is not', never the equality operators." Here is a quite good explanation why:

http://jaredgrubb.blogspot.com/2009/04/python-is-none-vs-none.html