# Python Regex Search Always False?

Tags: python, regex

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something very elementary here as I'm normally ok with Python & Regex. I'm looking to see if the string supplied contains at least one number, and this is the command line I'm going through, but always getting false...

```
>>> import re
>>> test_string = "123567890"
>>> pat = re.compile("[0-9]")
>>> pat.search(test_string) == True
False
```

Before posting this I've tried a few other permutations and not getting very far, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pat.search` doesn't return a Boolean value but a [MatchObject](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) so your comparison will fail:

```
In [9]: p = pat.search(test_string)

In [10]: p
Out[10]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x3cfa608>

In [11]: type(p)
Out[11]: _sre.SRE_Match
```

See [re.search](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html?highlight=re.search#re.search) docs:

> re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> Scan through string looking for a location where the regular
>   expression pattern produces a match, *and return a corresponding
>   MatchObject instance*. Return None if no position in the string matches
>   the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length
>   match at some point in the string.

Comment: Thank you, I misinterpreted the doc slightly where it says "Match Objects always have a boolean value of True, so that you can test whether e.g. match() resulted in a match with a simple if statement"!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `re.search()` method does not actually return a `bool`, it returns a specialized [regexp. match object](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects). `bool(pat.search(test_string))` should return `True`, viz.:

```
>>> import re
>>> test_string = "123567890"
>>> pat = re.compile("[0-9]")
>>> bool(pat.search(test_string))
True
```

The normal way to check for a successful match is simply to use the `if` construct, i.e.:

```
>>> if pat.search(test_string): True
... 
True
```

You can use this abbreviated form of truth-testing for any object that implements one of either the `__nonzero__` or  `__len__` special methods.

Answer (score 0):

[re.search](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) returns a [MatchObject](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) when it finds a match, not a boolean. It DOES return None when it doesn't match, so this would do what you're trying to do:

```
pat.search(test_string)!=None
```

Comment: When comparing with `None` you should use `is not None` (or `is None` for the inverse)

Comment: `is None`/`is not None` is preferred over the use of comparison operators. Because `is` can be implemented as a simple pointer comparison, it performs no method look-up and is slightly faster, it's semantically cleaner, and it guards against the (admittedly unlikely) scenario of the `__eq__` special method being overwritten (q.v., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166748/identity-versus-equality-for-none-in-python/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should use match objects.  I normally need more than a `True`/`False` from a match object, so I always save it away.

```
>>> m = pat.search(test_string)
>>> bool(m) == True
True
>>> if m:
        print "true"
true
```