# sqlalchemy: null comparison commutativity

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I just stumbled upon this behaviour of sqlalchemy:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import Column, null

>>> print(Column("x") == null())
x IS NULL
>>> print(Column("x") == None)
x IS NULL

>>> print(null() == Column("x"))
NULL = x
>>> print(None == Column("x"))
x IS NULL
```

Can someone explain why `==` is not commutative for `null()` while it is when using `None`? What's the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin, take a look at [Identity vs. Equailty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166748/identity-versus-equality-for-none-in-python) for an explanation on why your `None` conditions are both returning `x IS NULL`.

The reason why your `null()` clauses are returning different results is due to how the `operators` work.

As per the documentation, the operators work like the following:

> In a column context, produces the clause a = b. If the target is None, produces a IS NULL.

Explanation:

```
Column("x") == null() # a = b -> b is NullType; returning IS NULL

null() == Column('x') # a = b -> b is ColumnType; not returning IS NULL
```

For more information, you may view the [Sqlalchemy Docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement)

Comment: `None == Column("x")` calls `Column("x") == None` since the first comparison returns `NotImplemented`, therefore it works both ways - the Python part makes sense. The second question remains: is there any case in which one would actually want to obtain `NULL = `? The docs say "if the target is None", highlighting the 2nd argument, and looking at `sqlalchemy.sql.default_comparator._boolean_compare`, the function only handles the comparison separately if the 2nd argument is `None`/`Null` but not when the 1st is. Still, this behaviour seems like a bug to me or at least very unintuitive.

Comment: @chpolste I agree, it is not intuitive and more than likely a bug. If I knew how, I would report the bug to whomever maintains sqlalchemy.

Comment: @chpolste And as far as I am aware, I cannot think of any case where one would use `NULL =`