# Most succinct/low-hassle trick for identity comparison with None?

Tags: python

This question is frivolous but I consider it a quality-of-life/Python trivia issue.

I find myself writing `x is not None` often.  Is there a clever ***semantically equivalent*** way of writing that more succinctly?  Or is
this an example of the "only one way" maxim in action?

PEP 20, [*The Zen of Python*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

> There should be one--and preferably only one--obvious way to do it.

If anyone knows something magic, great.  *And* if you have tried and failed to figure something out, let yourself be counted.

Comment: Related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166748/identity-versus-equality-for-none-in-python?rq=1 as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no more succinct way to make this comparison than using the `is` operator.